# Checkout files from branch, without changing head nor changing any existing files

Tags: git

What is the best way to checkout/merge all files from a branch into the working directory, that currently do not exist there, but without changing the repository state, HEAD, or existing files?

Is this possible with a one line command?

Comment: That's a little difficult, if the branch you want to checkout has some files edited/changed that currently are modified in you current working directory otherwise you could have simply done git stash, git rebase [branchname], git stash pop. In any case your commit history is going to change.

Comment: Well, unfortunaly it will always be the case that files are in the working directory, that differ from the branch.

Comment: It's not *one line* but I think your best bet is to make a separate work-tree with a separate index (using `git worktree add` if you have it, or just a second clone) and then compare the separate work-tree.

Answer (score 0):

Git really doesn't want to do this -- it wants to switch branches or merge, or check out specific files by name.

You could use `tar` to skip files that exist, though.

```
git archive mybranch | tar x --skip-old-files
```