# `git checkout branch -- .`, without overwriting existing files

Tags: git, powershell, git-checkout

#### Context

I have a repository containing the development history for an application. The application is compiled on the fly from its source code to be used right after the repository has been cloned.

The application uses a couple of configuration files, which are declined in several configuration archetypes. For ease of deployment, I would like to store each archetype on a separate branch, and obtain both the application from `master` and the configuration from the selected branch after cloning.

The plain solution would be to base the configuration branches on `master`, but this requires regularly rebasing them all when `master` advances. I'm therefore trying out a solution with two separate git histories:

- The `master` branch contains the application's source code;
- All `config/<archetype>` stem from a separate root (created through `git checkout --orphan`), and only contain the build script and their respective configurations.

The build script must now retrieve all source code from `master` before building it, taking care not to overwrite the archetype configuration files with the default ones from `master`. Therefore...

#### Question

I need a variant of `git checkout <branch> -- .` that does *not* touch existing files, whatever their state (changed, unchanged, ignored, untracked...).

#### Leads

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052910/3233393) identical question which does have an answer (`git archive mybranch | tar x --skip-old-files`), however I'm encountering some issues:

- I'm using Powershell on Windows, which apparently provide a native `tar` command that does not have `--skip-old-files`;
- Git's version of `tar` accepts the flag, but fails due to what I assume is a quirk in how Powershell's pipeline works (the same command run from Git Bash works):

```
PS> &"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" archive master | &"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tar.exe" x --skip-old-files
/usr/bin/tar: Malformed extended header: missing newline
/usr/bin/tar: Substituting `.' for empty member name
/usr/bin/tar: Substituting `.' for empty member name
/usr/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
/usr/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

In this environment, I would much prefer a solution which only uses Git.

Comment: PowerShell does not directly support redirection of binary streams between native applications (*.exe). A workaround is to let cmd.exe do the redirection: `cmd /c "git archive master | tar x --skip-old-files"`

Comment: @zett42 that's my last resort, yes... though I sure do hope there's a more elegant solution :p

Comment: *"I'm therefore trying out a solution where all config/<archetype> are based on a separate root, and the script used to build the application first retrieves its source code from master (everything is properly .gitignored to prevent accidental commits), ensuring that existing configuration files are kept (effectively overriding the default ones)."* Could you rephrase this sentence please? I did not get the link from here to the **Question** part.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara wow, that parenthesis creep got me good. I rephrased it all into a more structured paragraph. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is exactly what you need but instead of a partial `checkout` you may want to use a `merge`, which is the standard way to resolve conflicting commits.

Considering that you are on an orphaned branch, you cannot use a simple `git merge` but you have to specify the option `--allow-unrelated-histories`. Since you want to script this, there cannot be any conflict: this should be straightforward with the right merging strategy, which could be `ours` given that you are in `config/<archetype>`. You also want your orphaned branch to remain untouched, still possible with `--no-commit` and a following `git reset --hard HEAD`. In the end, the merge command from `config/<archetype>` could be something like this (untested):

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -s recursive -Xours --no-commit master
```

Comment: I *knew* there would be an unexpected combination that would do that! Though `git reset --hard HEAD` undoes what the merge was doing, but `git reset` works perfectly. `--autostash` can be added for bonus points handling changed files :D

Comment: Git already provides anything you need in general :) About the hard reset I thought you wanted to clear the orphaned branch completely at the end of your script (after the merge I mean), but I misunderstood, sorry for that. Good point for the `--autostash` option!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd favor the `git archive ... | tar -x --skip-old-files` solution here, but consider the following:

- You're on some orphan branch *B* right now.  You have some set of files occupying your working tree.  You want these same files to appear in your working tree after extracting all the files that appear in the tip commit of `master`.
- Therefore, there are just two ways to achieve this:

  1. Extract files from `master` but don't touch any existing files: that's the solution that can be done with the pipe, which isn't working from PowerShell.  You could also construct a rather fancy "list all files and directories in the top level of the commit; for each such name, test whether it exists here; if not; extract that name from the commit; done" loop.  **Or**
  2. *Save* these files somewhere: copy or move them away, extract all files from master, then *put these files back*.

  Method 2 is relatively simple.  It's easy to achieve in the absence of subdirectories.  The presence of subdirectories makes both methods questionable: what if the working tree currently has a directory `d` and a file `f`, but the tip commit on `master` has a *file* named `d` and/or a *directory* named `f`?  What result would you like for this case?  (The `tar` method says *preserve whatever is here now* so you'll end up saving `d/*` and `f`, which you can choose to do manually with method 2.)

Once you decide on what to do about directory/file conflicts—these are a hard case for `git checkout` too, by the way—you can write the rest in some scripting language to implement method 2.  Use `mktemp -d` or equivalent to make a place to hide all the existing files for the duration of the `git checkout`.